# Explanation of a certain polymorphic behavior in C#

Tags: c#, polymorphism

I've found that it is possible to create an instance of a child class and assign it to a variable of type parent class. I cannot wrap my head around this scenario.

Here in my code, though the instance is of `Human` class. It logs "i am an Animal" in the console

I have a few question regarding this:

1. What does it even mean?
2. What is the possible outcome?
3. Why & when would someone do this kind of stuff?

Parent class:

```
public class Species
{
    public  String Shout()
    {
        return "I am an animal";
    }
}
```

Child class:

```
public class Human : Species
{
    public new String Shout()
    {
        return "I am a Human";
    }
}
```

Instantiation:

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Species h = new Human();

        Console.WriteLine(h.Shout());
    }
}
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Polymorphism is very useful if you want to efficiently use Object Oriented Programming or OOP.

Let's say that you own a zoo. Inside this zoo there are (obviously) some animals. If you would want to store them all inside one array or list, you would have to use a [**base type**](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/base) for them, in this case `Animal`. Now, classes that derive from our base type `Animal` share the same properties, therefore also the same methods.

```
class Animal
{
    public string Shout ()
    { 
        return "I am an animal!"; 
    }
}
```

Let's now declare a class for a lion.

```
class Lion : Animal
{
}
```

Even though we haven't written the `Shout` method inside the `Lion` class, instances of `Lion` will *also* have the `Shout` method available to them, since they *derive* from the `Animal` class.

But what if we want the `Lion` class to `Shout` something different? We can make use of the `virtual` and `override` keywords. These can be used on properties and methods. `virtual` means the method or property *can* be overridden, while `override` performs the actual override. Both need to be set the right place for this to work.

To override our `Shout` method, we will have to mark it as `virtual` first.

```
public virtual string Shout () { ... }
```

Now, in our `Lion` class, we can perform an override on the `Shout` method.

```
public override string Shout ()
{
    return "Rooooaaar, I am a lion!";
}
```

Now that we clarified this, let's look at some usage of it.

---

```
Lion lion1 = new Lion();
```

This creates a new instance of the `Lion` class by calling the class' constructor. If we call `lion1.Shout()` now, we would get `"Rooooaaar, I am a lion!"` as the returned value.

```
Animal animal1 = new Lion();
```

This works as well! Since our `Lion` class derives from the base type `Animal`, the object can be stored inside an object of the type `Animal`. But don't be fooled! If we call `animal1.Shout()` now, we would still get `"Rooooaaar, I am a lion!"` returned.

```
Animal animal2 = new Animal();
```

This would just be an instance of the base class, meaning that the method `animal2.Shout()` would return `"I am an animal!"`.

---

Let's now say that we have some more animals, `Cat`, `Dog`, and `Lion`. Without using polymorphism, we couldn't store them inside a single array, since they have nothing in common! However, if they do derive from the `Animal` class, we can just do something like this:

```
List<Animal> animals = new List<Animal>();
animals.Add(new Cat());
animals.Add(new Dog());
animals.Add(new Lion());
animals.Add(new Animal());
```

All of these above would work perfectly fine!

Lastly, if you want to retrieve an element from this `Animal` list and you want to call some `Dog`-specific methods on it, you can (if it is actually a `Dog` object, of course) use `animals[1] as Dog` to convert it to a `Dog` object. However, if it isn't a `Dog` object, you would just get `null` back from the `as` operator.

Answer (score 2):

> What does it even mean ?

**[Polymorphism](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/classes-and-structs/polymorphism) - *Poly* means *many*, *morph* means *forms***

Thus *polymorphism* means having many forms. In object-oriented programming paradigm, polymorphism is often expressed as 'one interface, multiple functions'. - [Tutorials Point](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/csharp/csharp_polymorphism.htm)

> What is the possible outcome and

Well as from your code:

```
Species h = new Human();
Console.WriteLine(h.Shout()); //calling Shout method of Species
```

The output will be : `I am an animal`

Here you are calling the`Shout` method of `Species`(base parent) of `Human`(child) by instantiating `h` as of *type* `Species`.

> Why & when would someone do this kind of stuff

Also from your example you can call the `shout` method of `Human` with the help of `casting`

```
Console.WriteLine(((Human)h).Shout());  //calling Shout method of Human
```

The output will be : `I am an human`.

Here I casted `h` as `Human` by doing this `((Human)h)` for better readability you can also do `h as Human` and then you call the `Shout` method of `Human` class.

```
Console.WriteLine((h as Human).Shout());  //calling Shout method of Human
```

Check the [Fiddle](https://dotnetfiddle.net/tyAWv8)

---

PS: You should also take note of what @Willem said

> You should not use new. But make Shout virtual and use override in the Shout of Human

---

Basically polymorphism is done to **overload** methods(check overriding and virtual usage) of the same name but having different *datatype* as parameters or different *datatype* by itself, within a child class, a parent class or between a child and parent

Answer (score 1):

Not a full answer to your question, but if you want your code to display "I am a Human" do the following:

Parent class :

```
public class Species
{
    public virtual  String Shout()
    {
         return "I am an animal";
     }
  }
```

Child class :

```
 public class Human : Species
 {
    public override String Shout()
    {
         return "I am a Human";
     }
}
```

For a full answer to your questions, you should really look at a textbook or article on polymorphism.

Answer (score 0):

As a business example, imaging you are writing a program where you need specific actions taken on an object. The object may have gone through this program before but needs to go a different route. You can set it up to use polymorphism and override the methods you need to change. For example:

Imaging a base class of ImageProcess that has an override for ProcessPicture.

ProcessPicture may do some cropping and cleanup before it's reviewed or has data pulled from it in another program. The program sends it back, but this time ProcessPicture needs to add a watermark.

In this way we can have a single program do different tasks depending on the status of the image.

Comment: This is technically correct, I suppose, but does not really provide a good explanation for how your abstraction relates to programming, nor does it provide any details about what the actual process looks like in either code-form or abstracted 'business example' form.